# How to show data label values in Cognos 11

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I am using Cognos 11 to build a report. I am using a bar graph and I am trying to show actual values on top of each bar. Below is a picture of the graph I am trying to create. The writing in red is what I ultimately want to show for all bars.

[image]

I have tried everything but cant seem to find out how to do this. I think cognos 11 just may not support it. Any ideas or suggestions on how to show each bars values specific number in Cognos?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on some factors:

- What class of visualization are you using?  (11.1, 11.0, legacy,
  charts)
- What kind of visualization is that?  (I assume clustered
  column)

Here are a couple examples to get you started.

For 11.1, clustered column:

1. Select the visualization.
2. Change the *Show value labels* property to *Yes*.

For charts, clustered column:

1. Select the visualization.
2. Click *Select a chart object* and select *Bar*.
3. Set the *Show values* properties by clicking on the ellipsis.